# Project is Missing Required Source Folder: "src_ex_common"

Tags: classpath, src, buildpath

I try to open the sample project from google opensource as provided in the following link:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git

I have imported the 5 git repositories as required in the program but there is still a red exclamation mark near the project and the "Problems" suggested the project is missing required source folder "src_ex_common". I right click the project name => Properties => Java Build Path => Source, i saw 
"MainProjectActivity/src_ex_common (missing)".

I right clicked the project name => new=>source folder and attempt to name a new folder called "src_ex_common" but eclipse said **The folder is already a source folder**. Then i tried to name a new folder called "src_ex_common" in Windows. The problem above is solved but there are many errors then appear in various java files under src.

I googled that some said this might be due to the problem in ".classpath"
The detail of .classpath is listed below:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src_ex_common"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>`

Did anyone encounter this problem before? Great if u would share your approach to tackle it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the `mkprojectfile` file in the root folder, you will see that the `src_ex_common` folder is linked to the `commons` library:

```
    <link>
        <name>src_ex_common</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <location>SRC_ROOT_DIR/frameworks/ex/common/java</location>
    </link>
```

You can import this project from the same [ex repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/) that contains the `chips` dependency.

Comment: @AntoineMurion you should upvote (and accept what you've done of course) instead of writing such comments.